# how to create and open the hyperlink in code?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

13 minutes ago | LINK

In xaml, a hyperlink can be set as

```
 <HyperlinkButton Content="Website"  NavigateUri="mysite" TargetName="_blank"/>
```

then when user click on it, the link will open.

How all those can be done in code-behind: create hyperlink and open it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xaml

```
<HyperlinkButton 
     Content="Website" Click="HyperlinkClick"
     NavigateUri="mysite" TargetName="_blank" x:Name="hyperlink" />
```

Code behind

```
private void HyperlinkClick(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(hyperlink.NavigateUri);
}
```

or

```
private void HyperlinkClick(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(hyperlink.NavigateUri, hyperlink.TargetName);
}
```